How to remove the vscode minimap on the right side only for a single file?
from other questions I see we can disable the minimap entirely with
"editor.minimap.enabled": false
However, I only want to use this minimap for one of my gigantic large files... all other files I don't want it to show up because they are relatively small...
I am working on a laptop so the minimap screenspace on multiple panes is expensive. I only want it to show up for my main file...
How can I only have the minimap show up for this specific file?
Will I need to write a custom extension that overrides the minimap toggle rendering code?

you can have a look at the extension I wrote When File, you can modify settings based on file path/name/extension
